# SerpentAI Error When Creating a Game Plugin

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I recently installed SerpentAI and I'm having an issue when creating a game plugin.

When running the command:

```
serpent generate game
```

I provide it with the following answers:

- RaftWars
- web_browser

  ```
  What is the name of the game? (Titleized, No Spaces i.e. AwesomeGame):
  ```

  RaftWars
  How is the game launched? (One of: 'steam', 'executable', 'web_browser'):
  web_browser
  OFFSHOOT: Attempting to install SerpentRaftWarsGamePlugin...

  OFFSHOOT PLUGIN INSTALL: Verifying that plugin dependencies are installed...

  OFFSHOOT PLUGIN INSTALL: Installing files...

  There was a problem during installation... Reverting!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "**main**", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\marce\SerpentAI\plugins\SerpentRaftWarsGamePlugin\plugin.py", line 28, in 
      offshoot.executable_hook(SerpentRaftWarsGamePlugin)
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\base.py", line 185, in executable_hook
      plugin_class.install()
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 35, in install
      cls.install_files()
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 118, in install_files
      raise e
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 91, in install_files
      is_valid, messages = cls._validate_file_for_pluggable(plugin_file_path, file_dict["pluggable"])
    File "c:\users\marce\anaconda3\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 235, in _validate_file_for_pluggable
      raise PluginError("The Plugin definition specifies an invalid pluggable: %s => %s" % (file_path, pluggable))
  offshoot.plugin.PluginError: The Plugin definition specifies an invalid pluggable: plugins\SerpentRaftWarsGamePlugin\files\serpent_RaftWars_game.py => Game

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem I found that it was caused by trying to generate a game with the same name as one that already has a plugin. If this is also the case for you, then go into `C:\Users\___\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\plugins` and delete the plugin that already exists. After this, run through the steps of the tutorial again, taking care to cd into `C:\Users\___\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\` before running `conda activate serpent`.

Comment: "taking care to cd into C:\Users\___\Anaconda3\envs\serpent\ before running conda activate serpent" This was the problem for me. I forgot to cd into my SerpentAI directory

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but my `serpent\plugins\` directory is empty and I make sure I have cd into my SerpentAI directory before activate serpent. The error still exists, I have no idea what's going on.
When running the command:

```
serpent generate game
```

I provide it with the following answers:

```
    Ballance
    executable
```