# SerpentAI Error: The Plugin definition specifies an invalid pluggable

Tags: python-3.x

I recently installed SerpentAI and I'm having an issue when creating a game plugin.

When running the command:
'''
serpent generate game
'''

It throws errors like [SerpentAI Error When Creating a Game Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962625/serpentai-error-when-creating-a-game-plugin) The inside is the same, and I tried the inside method, but it didn't work. Someone can help me

```
What is the name of the game? (Titleized, No Spaces i.e. AwesomeGame):
THProject
How is the game launched? (One of: 'steam', 'executable', 'web_browser'):
executable
c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\base.py:38: UserWarning: 'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.
  warnings.warn("'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.")
c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\base.py:38: UserWarning: 'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.
  warnings.warn("'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.")
OFFSHOOT: Attempting to install SerpentTHProjectGamePlugin...
c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\base.py:38: UserWarning: 'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.
  warnings.warn("'offshoot.yml' not found! Using default configuration.")

OFFSHOOT PLUGIN INSTALL: Verifying that plugin dependencies are installed...


OFFSHOOT PLUGIN INSTALL: Installing files...


There was a problem during installation... Reverting!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\plugins\SerpentTHProjectGamePlugin\plugin.py", line 28, in <module>
    offshoot.executable_hook(SerpentTHProjectGamePlugin)
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\base.py", line 185, in executable_hook
    plugin_class.install()
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 35, in install
    cls.install_files()
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 118, in install_files
    raise e
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 91, in install_files
    is_valid, messages = cls._validate_file_for_pluggable(plugin_file_path, file_dict["pluggable"])
  File "c:\users\28734\.conda\envs\serpent\lib\site-packages\offshoot\plugin.py", line 235, in _validate_file_for_pluggable
    raise PluginError("The Plugin definition specifies an invalid pluggable: %s => %s" % (file_path, pluggable))
offshoot.plugin.PluginError: The Plugin definition specifies an invalid pluggable: plugins\SerpentTHProjectGamePlugin\files\serpent_THProject_game.py => Game
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Installed 'serpent.game'.
All third-party libraries in the agent are sufficient. Some libraries are not installed